# Clojure TCP client using Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, clojure

I am trying to write a simple TCP client which sends a request to a remote host using Java `Socket`. The application is synchronous, so it will first transmit and receive and will block until the response is received.

I am able to create a Socket connection with the remote host and it seems I am able to send the request without a problem, however I never receive a response from the server, and so it ends up hanging.

Also, a look at Wireshark does not seem to indicate any datagram sent or received to/from the specified host IP (I should add that the host is accessed via VPN, which I have verified that I can ping on the command line). It sounds like this might be a network issue, but just in case I thought it would be worth a sanity check to see if there might be a problem with the code:

```
(defn- receive
  "Given a reader and a socket, create a DataInputStream and process the server
  response"
  [reader socket]
  (let [byte-in (make-array Byte/TYPE b/max-message-size)]
    (log/receive socket b/max-message-size)
    (.read reader byte-in)
    byte-in))

(defn- transmit
  "Given a writer, a socket and a message, create a DataOutputStream 
  and send request to the server"
  [writer socket message]
  (let [byte-out (r/make-request socket message)]
    (log/begin-transmit socket byte-out)
    (.write writer byte-out)
    (log/end-transmit writer)
    (.flush writer)))

(defn send-request
  "Given a message, create a Socket and process the request"
  [msg]
  (with-open [socket (java.net.Socket.  (:host-ip msg) (:host-port msg))
              writer (DataOutputStream. (.getOutputStream socket))
              reader (DataInputStream.  (.getInputStream socket))]
    (println "Initializing TCP request ...\n")
    (transmit writer socket msg)
    (receive reader socket)))
```

Here is the output as well from the Transmission -- it hangs during the Receive function. Note that the Host IP and Host Ports indicated were taken from the fields of the `Socket` object instance:

```
Transmitting request
 -------------------------------
    Message Size : 123 bytes
    Host IP      : /192.168.xxx.xxx
    Host Port    : 2605

Bytes written: 123 bytes

Receiving response
 --------------------------------
    Maximum Size : 146 bytes
    Host IP      : /192.168.xxx.xxx
    Host Port    : 2605
```

Comment: Did you try running it with server app? E.g. set up simple echo server on local machine and connect to it using your clojure client?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try creating a simple server to run locally to see if it is in fact a problem with the client or a network issue.

Comment: It appears that the test server was misconfigured. The server admin has since corrected the problem and now I am back in business.